# Salesforce for building real world applications

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, visualforce-component

Is there any resource available for creating or building a real world application in salesforce which uses APEX and Visualforce SLDS components. Or can I build such type of apps.

Can you my friends give me some example also so that I can understand the salesforce in more depth.

Like the trailhead has many projects but they are just running in salesforce development environment. 
But I want to use the app build on salesforce in Android. Like we have facebook, instagram, amazon, calculator apps in android.

Comment: they have appExchange. you can go and search there for your specific app...

Comment: @SagarHinsu Thank you for your reply. Actually I don't want to use the apps but I want to learn how to create an app using salesforce for any small or big business so that they can use them on there mobile phones also. Can I build the same?

Comment: creating an salesforce app is quite a big process.. you can think of some idea and start implementing that. create lightning component visualforce page and apex class for that. after that you can create an package for that and use as an app

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Salesforce Mobile Developer Center](https://developer.salesforce.com/devcenter/mobile), if you're interested in writing your own mobile apps, and you can always use the available [Mobile Apps](https://www.salesforce.com/solutions/mobile/overview/) if you're just interested in writing Visualforce/Lightning and running them on your phone. As far as "real world" applications written for use with phones, the possibilities are nearly limitless, with everything from customer service, sales, technical support, billing, customer portals, maps to specific locations (e.g. nearest sales center or repair shops), and so on. Really, the limitations are mostly whatever you can imagine.

As one of the most successful examples, consider [Starbucks Ideas](https://ideas.starbucks.com/). This is written on the force.com platform, and allows customers to submit ideas and vote on them (just like Salesforce Ideas). This is all integrated with Salesforce, including workflow rules to alert management of popular ideas, etc, and works in the mobile experience as well. They could have chose to write an app for it, but didn't. My organization did decide to release a mobile app powered by Salesforce that lets customers find repair shops, order products online, browse products, request support, etc.

And remember, almost *anything* you can run run in a Salesforce Development Org can you can run on your phone, too. Obviously, the smaller screen space means you'll want to learn about responsive design, and probably the [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/), but that's mostly implementation details. As you've already found the trailheads, I suggest you complete as many of the development/mobile trails as you can, and then find yourself some challenges to complete. Just think of something you think would be really awesome to have on your phone, then try to build it.

I've written some neat stuff in the past, like a mobile signature component so people can sign off on documents using their fingers on a phone or tablet, and others I've seen include integrating maps, barcode readers, optical character recognition, project management, and so on. You might even browse the AppExchange and just take a look at some of the components there, and try to build your own version of them, or look at existing projects on github.com, or even learn about [Lightning Strike](https://lightningstrike.io/), which is a collection of components with source code.

The point is, the answers you seek are out there if you look for them, and we'll be here to help you with specific questions as possible. All you need to do is find a point where you want to get started and begin your journey. Nobody can really tell you where that starting point is, but we can help you on your way when you get lost.

Comment: A great answer to my question. Thank you. A great help from your side. Salesforce is very big to learn. But I am trying hard to better understand the salesforce.

Comment: So, I read about hybrid apps and SLDS in salesforce. It means I can build an app template or UI in HTML5 with jquery mobile or angular js or backbone js and integrate it with salesforce using REST APIs and fetching the sobjects using remote object calling with javascript. Am I right, @sfdcfox ?

Comment: @SagarPanwar Yes, you can build hybrid apps, use REST APIs, etc. You can also write native apps to take advantage of native hardware, etc. Like I said, almost anything you can imagine is possible.

Comment: Okay. Now I am getting some idea what actually I want. :-) And if any problem I face you guys are always here to help each other. Thank you @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a Community Cloud, then set page access to public. Thus people don't have to log in to use your app. On the individual pages, you can easily include Lightning Components.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the Lightning Design System and can create a web app or mobile app using Salesforce REST APIs.

If you want to learn more about the mobile app using Salesforce platform capabilities then here is the link to a doc.

[Getting Started With Salesforce Mobile](https://developer.salesforce.com/mobile/getting-started/android)

[Salesforce REST APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/)